# unresolved reference: activity errors

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I am building functions to write variables from editText fields to sharedPreferences.

I have tried several possibilities for writing to sharedPreferences, and none have worked so decided to write my own. So i have made the related TextView fields onClick'able, which then runs the write to sharedPreferences functions.

```
package com.taylorworld.tw01

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.content_main.*

class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    //setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar))

    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show()
    }
    }

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is                  present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_settings -> true
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
   }

    var strength = editText2.text.toString()
    var dexterity = editText.text.toString()
    var intelligance = editText4.text.toString()
    var wisdom = editText3.text.toString()
    var constitution = editText6.text.toString()
    var charisma = editText5.text.toString()
    var chrname = editText7.text.toString()

    val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    public fun saveStr(view: View) {

        val sharedPref = activity?.setPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return with(sharedPref.edit()) {
            putInt(getString(STR), strength)
            commit()
        }
     }

    public fun saveDex(view: View) {

        val sharedPref = activity?.setPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return with(sharedPref.edit()) {
            putInt(getString(DEX), dexterity)
            commit()
        }
     }

     public fun readStr(view: View) {

    }
    }
```

I get 'unresolved reference: activity' errors from line 50, 54 and 62, and cant work out how to resolve the errors.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There's no line numbers here, where is 50, 54 and 62? And which errors did you get? Which "several possibilities" did you try? Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) when you have the time, it will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Thank you. those line numbers contain,  val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)   val sharedPref = activity?.setPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return  and val sharedPref = activity?.setPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return . I get the 'unresolved reference: activity' error from those three lines in my above posted MainActivity.kt. My git repo commits say it pretty well, within the code i have tried to achieve it, ie those possibilities i have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things that aren't quite ideal about this code, but to get you started with an answer to your immediate question:

Activities don't have an `activity` member (variable or function) that you can reference. However, the points at which you're trying to reference `activity` are themselves part of `MainActivity`'s scope and because `MainActivity` is itself an `Activity` (via its inheritance from `AppCompatActivity`), so you can simply replace `activity.` with `this.`. You can simplify even further and just delete the `this.` prefix for those calls, as well.

Give that a shot and see if you can't figure it out from there. If you can't, I'll be glad to help some more!

Comment: Using 'this' instead of activity has solved that error. I am however getting the following errors, https://imagebin.ca/v/4hpY6MAqnwMi , the interesting one is the mismatch type error, now chrname will be a string, however all the others will be intergers, hence using putInt, however within the variable definitions, can i use something like toInteger() so it recognises those as integers instead of strings? I should also point out, i have used the code from https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences adapted to my needs to try and get this working.

Comment: https://github.com/brobostigon/TW01/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/taylorworld/tw01/MainActivity.kt got a version working, and saves the editText fields to sharedPreferences.

Comment: @philiptaylor looks good to me! One thing I noticed in that working version: Those `saveXXX(view: View)` functions have a lot of similar functionality. You could refactor that functionality out into a common function.

Comment: cool, Thank you, :). That is a good idea, that's how i have been writing the retrieve function, ie it retrieves them all within the same function,

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! If you think I've helped you answer your question, would you mind accepting my answer so others don't see this as unanswered?